# how to get html  header's element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

as i want to send the file names which is included in  `<head> section e.g. css & js file name` including it's container *folder* to the server side via `ajax`.
please note that, in given example the `css & js` are located inside of *files* folder.
***so how can i get the css & js file names including it's container***

```
<html> <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="files/sample.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="files/jquery.js"> </script>
</head>
```

Now i need to consider about other things too, ***sample.CSS***

```
    #myImage {
       background: url('image/lucy.jpg'); 
  /* also i need to get these image file name including details with location */
    }
```

Comment: can you be a bit more explicit? I mean, do you want to get the actual filenames of the css/jss files included or do you want to parse those files and extract the images?

Comment: ok. i want to get `included css & js` file name also the _image file_ name if used in `css`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is to get the resources names (stylesheets and scripts) in your `head` element :

```
function filterName(path){
    path = path.split('/');
    return path[path.length - 1];
}
var styleSheets = [];
$('head link[rel=stylesheet]').each(function(){
    styleSheets.push(filterName($(this).attr('href'));
});
var scripts = [];
$('head script[src]').each(function(){
    scripts.push(filterName($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

It's rather hard to actual parse these files and compute their fullpath. To get all the images, you may consider to traverse all of the dom elements and check if they have any `background-image` attached to them through css :

```
function filterBgImage(n){
    var m = n.match(/url\(["'](.*?)["']\)/);
    if(m && m.length == 2)
        return m[1];
    return n;
}
var imgs = [];
$('*')
    .filter(function(){
        var a =  $(this).css('background-image');
        return a != '' && a != 'none';
    })
    .each(function(){
        imgs.push(filterBgImage($(this).css('background-image')));
    });
```

The good thing about this approach is that you do not have to transform the relative path into full path, because jquery is doing that for you.

Comment: gion, it's working for me but one thing i need clarification from you.  if i use `path = path.split(/) : returns jquery.js` when _path = path.split(' "" ')_ `returns files/jquery.js`. as i wanted to return `files/jquery.js`. am i correct? if use path.split(' "" ');

Comment: if you want to return the actual relative path, do not use the `filterName` function anymore. That was just to get the name of the files by removing the path that you, in fact, need.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you want to do is possible from a web browser - but there are tools that will do it without -> http://www.httrack.com/html/overview.html